# Setting random background color on a css class

Tags: php, html, css

I want to set a random background color on a css-class... I already got this PHP-Code:

```
<?php $color = sprintf(“#%06x”,rand(0,16777215)); ?>
```

This is my style.php:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/css');

?>

body {
    background: INSERT PHP COLOR HERE - BUT HOW?;
}
```

Comment: `body {background-color: <?php echo $color; ?>;}`  Exactly the same as if you needed to insert it into HTML.

Comment: Hopefully your real code doesn't have those slanty quotes in the `sprintf()` `“#%06x”`.  You need real double quotes for PHP code. `"#%06x"`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski which is, I guess, a pretty bad idea by itself :-)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Then I didn't say anything :P

Comment: @JanDvorak I don't think so, it's pretty common actually.  CSS itself has no way of propagating a variable through so you can't easily change a color across a whole set of css. Useful for variable themeing, stuff like that.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski what about "_uncacheable_ generated CSS is a bad idea"?

Comment: @JanDvorak who says it's uncacheable? If the values only change when you change them in code, it will be cached. I'm not talking about always building a completely variable set of CSS rules on each load, just about propagating color vars through as the OP is doing.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski `rand(0,16777215)` looks uncacheable to me ;-)

Comment: @JanDvorak But when done properly, the variable values like this random one are only applied last.  Plain static CSS files are sent down first, then the few dynamic rules that must be cascaded over are sent in the dynamic file last, so only one file changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

is this what you want:

```
body {
    background: <?php echo $color; ?>;
}
```

the complete line would be:

```
<?php
$color = sprintf("#%06x",rand(0,16777215));
header('Content-Type: text/css');
?>
body {
    background: <?php echo $color; ?>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

and where is your question? just kidding.

insert the variable directly in the mentioned css line.

```
body {
  background: <?php echo $color?>;
}
```

to get it working ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?=$color; ?>
```

The body is inside the PHP document?

Answer (score 0):

Why not make a array with colors to pick random color from?

```
<?php
$input = array("#000080", "#00CED1", "#191970");
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);
echo $input[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";
echo $input[$rand_keys[1]] . "\n";
?>
```

Just replace the names with hex codes.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

Answer (score 0):

Change your file like this.

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/css');
    $color = sprintf(“#%06x”,rand(0,16777215));
?>

body {
    background: <?php echo  $color; ?>;
}
```