# Create a random background color in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I've checked out all the related questions I could find and still cannot get this to work so am reaching out to you lovely folk!

I wish my site to have a random color background (one of multiple pre-selected colors) each time someone visits.

There are various times people have asked for it to call up a random image but I just wish to have a block color, assuming using bold background.

The two options I have seen used in similar ways, but to no avail, are:

**jQuery ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18116470/random-background-colour-picker-for-tumblr): taken from a Tumblr query):**

1) Creating a new 'background.js' file in /js/ with the code:

```
    <script>
    var bgcolorlist=new Array("background: #ff871b", "background: #15efa1", "background: #51ddff", "background: #ff1b6c", "background: #000000");
    var color = bgcolorlist[Math.floor(Math.random()*bgcolorlist.length)];
    $('body').css('backgroundColor', color);
</script>
```

2) Adding to function.php:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
function add_my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'your-script', // name your script so that you can attach other scripts and de-register, etc.
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/your-script.js', // this is the location of your script file
        array('jquery') // this array lists the scripts upon which your script depends
    );
}
```

**& PHP and CSS ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530556/setting-random-background-color-on-a-css-class)):**

I put this whole string in the style.css file:

```
<?php
$input = array("#000080", "#00CED1", "#191970");
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);
echo $input[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";
echo $input[$rand_keys[1]] . "\n";
?>
body {
background: <?php echo  $color; ?>;
}
```

Unfortunately neither of these solutions seem to work for me and both threads are outdated so cannot get further answers hence starting a new thread.

1. Any ideas for where I might be going wrong for either?
2. Any other ways around this you think would be a better way to solve the problem?

Further info: I'm using the super simple [Less theme](http://lessmade.com/themes/less/), which only comes with 3 files: functions.php, index.php and style.css - which I'm using as a bare bones theme to completely customise my own theme.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your JavaScript implementation is that you have the whole CSS declaration in your array indexes. Also, since you are including the script in the head, you need to wrap the code in a [document.ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) handler, and take care of the [noConflict mode WordPress puts jQuery in](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers).

Try something like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var bgcolorlist=["#ff871b", "#15efa1", "#51ddff", "#ff1b6c", "#000000"];
    var color = bgcolorlist[Math.floor(Math.random()*bgcolorlist.length)];
    $('body').css('backgroundColor', color);
});
```

The reason your PHP did not work in the CSS file is because `.css` files do not normally run PHP code. You would need to put it in a separate `.php` file and enqueue it, or put the code in the `head` with `header.php` or an action.

```
<style>
<?php
$input = array("#000080", "#00CED1", "#191970");
$rand_key = array_rand($input);
$color = $input[$rand_key];
?>
body {
    background: <?php echo $color; ?>;
}
?>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Alexander! I tried a couple of the suggestions here but your jQuery update seems to be the simplest even though it requires an external file to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put PHP in the CSS file, so if you want to use a PHP approach, you would want to echo a local CSS  block in the header.

For example, in your functions.php file:

```
function getBgColor() {
    $input = array("#000080", "#00CED1", "#191970");
    return $input[rand(0, count($input) - 1)];
}
```

Then in your header.php:

```
<style>
    body {
        background: <?php echo getBgColor(); ?>;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks bobdye but I couldn't get this to work - does the style code need to be in <head>? I don't have a header.php in my theme but tried dropping it into index.php <head> but to no avail.

Comment: I noticed that there were a couple of typos in the PHP function. Try with the changes. Yes, it should go in the <head>, either in a header.php template or in index.php.